# Prevent waking from sleep with USB mouse?

Tags: imac, sleep-wake, mouse

I have an iMac running El Capitan.  I put my iMac to sleep because it's faster than hibernate and only uses 1.2 watts anyways.  But every time the mouse is moved, it wakes it up.

How do I stop a USB mouse (NOT bluetooth!) from waking the Mac?  I like that the keyboard wakes it, just not the mouse, because sometimes it gets moved out of the way, or the cat moves it.

This is a simple power option in both Windows and Linux but I can't seem to find the same option in MacOS.  Please don't answer with placing the mouse upside down, or in a box etc, this is not a solution for me, neither is shutting it off or hibernating it.  I'd like some kind of OS or hardware option.

Comment: Is this an Apple branded mouse, or a third-party product?

Comment: @IconDaemon I've used the Apple mouse and my Logitech mouse, both wake the computer. I'd rather use my Logitech mouse because of the forward/back thumb buttons.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to do this in software so I'd suggest doing it in hardware: unplug the mouse slightly and plug it back in to wake up the computer :)

Comment: @ToddDabney Thanks Todd but I don't consider that a valid solution. Especially considering the USB ports on the back of the screen, which is sitting on a very deep desk, is hard to reach for me, and my wife can't reach at all.